# Membership to a set/list as a key in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For example lets say I have `n` sets like:

```
states1 = {"AL","AZ","CA"}
states2 = {"CO","NJ","NY"}
states3 = {"GA","IN","OK"}
...
```

Sets are disjoint.

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column "state". I would like to create a new column "level" which would take the value `x` if "state" is in `states1`, `y` if in `states2`, and so forth, where each set corresponds to a value.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Best way I can come up with is declaring these sets as frozensets and creating a dictionary with these sets as keys. Then I guess I could loop through all of the keys of this dict and check for membership of a state to each set and choose the corresponding value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sets are disjoint, you can create a dictionary like this:

```
{"AL": x, "AZ": x, "CA": x, "CO": y, "NJ": y, "NY": y, ...}
```